# How can I fix Detox Package subpath './build/cli/args' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: react-native, detox

I am setting up detox for react native project and I have been working on the configs and when i sis the `detox build --configuration android` the build succeeded but when I am trying to run the `detox test --configuration android` I will end up getting following error `detox[13452] ERROR: [cli.js] Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './build/cli/args' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/Desktop/vahingonsattuessa/node_modules/jest-cli/package.json`

My `.detoxrc.json` file is looking as follows:

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "apps": {
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 12"
      }
    },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your template declaration.

Change:

```
const referenceTemplate = path.resolve(`.src/templates/reference.js`)
```

To:

```
const referenceTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/reference.js`)
```

In addition, your `localizedSlug` function seems to receive some wrong parameters. It seems to receive `isPage` as `false`, setting the URL to `/blog`, so check your query values.

Comment: Why does the url show `blog\test-reference` though ?

Comment: Something odd in `localizedSlug`. It's difficult to guess without knowing what parameters are sent there but for sure, there's something wrong. Try to debug there.

Comment: I added the localized slug in the question

Comment: Is receiving the `isPage` as `false` returning `return isDefault ? /blog/${slug}` : `/${locale}/blog/${slug}` (`/blog`)

Comment: Can you debug more about what's happening there? The issue should come from your query since the values are passed from the query object to the function.

Comment: I tried to debug but haven't been able to figure it out yet. It seems to whatever reason it takes the `/blog` there, does it need some kind of if else logic or some changes?

Comment: The issue relies on your source that is passing a wrong value. You can also change your logic to bypass it too.

Comment: I tried to do something like this `path:
                    index === 0
                        ? `references`
                        : `${references/page/${index + 1}`,```  but still saw the `blog/test-reference`

Comment: This fixed the other but last one is still broken ```exports.localizedSlug = ({ isDefault, locale, slug, isPage }) => {
    if (isPage) {
        return isDefault ? `/${slug}` : `/${locale}/${slug}`
    }
    return isDefault
        ? `/blog/${slug}`
        : `/${locale}/blog/${slug}` || isDefault
        ? `/services/${slug}`
        : `/${locale}/services/${slug}` || isDefault
        ? `/references/${slug}`
        : `/${locale}/references/${slug}`
}```